# ASP.NET data binding multiple format

Tags: c#, date, webforms, entity-framework-5

I have a ASP.NET 4.5 web forms site using EF 5.

One of the object of my data model is a 'medical file' with a DateTime property (among the others):

```
public partial class MedFile {
    public System.Guid MedFileId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> MedDate { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Here it is the snippet of the web form for editing:

```
<asp:ListView ID="MedFilesForm" runat="server" 
    ItemType="MedFile" DataKeyNames="MedFileId" 
    SelectMethod="GetFiles"
    UpdateMethod="UpdateFile">
    ...
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="TextBox1">Name</asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' />

        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="TextBox2">Data</asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MedDate", "{0:d}") %>' />

        <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server"
            CausesValidation="true" CommandName="Update"
        </asp:LinkButton>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Note the **UpdateMethod="UpdateFile"** and the **TextBox2** with the *Bind("MedDate", "{0:d}")*.

Finally here it is the UpdatedFile in the code behind:

```
public void UpdateFile(Guid medFileId) {
    // get the current med file from DB
    MedFile medfile = _cartellaBLL.GetMedFileByFileId(medFileId);
    // update it with values taken from the web form
    TryUpdateModel(medfile);
    // save the updated med file
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
       _cartellaBLL.UpdateFile(medfile);
    }
    ...
}
```

As known, the above **TryUpdateModel(medfile)** auto-magically validates, parses and converts the fields in the web form updating the passed medfile variable.

In particular, it validates and converts the value of the TextBox2 according to the date format of the application's culture possibly set in the web.config file:

```
<globalization culture="it-IT" uiCulture="it-IT" />
```

My problem is that I'd like the user would be able to **set the date in the webform using one of two possible formats**: the one of the default culture, in my case dd/MM/yyyy (Italy), and the international yyyy-MM-dd (ISO 8601).

Is it possible to instruct **TryUpdateModel(TModel)** to 'accept' both the format?

Comment: Your question is specific to dates, but you didn't show a single date in your code.  We don't have a crystal ball to tell us what your model loos like or what your business logic does.  We only know what you post here. Please edit your question to be reproducible and illustrate the specific problem you are describing.  Thanks.

Comment: I am sorry. I rewrote the question above. Now I hope it is clear enough.